# Converting JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

For reference, this is the JSON I'm working with: http://goo.gl/xxHci0

In regular JavaScript, using the code below works fine and I can manipulate it easily:

```
var info = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML);
alert(info[0]["AssetId"]);
```

But I'm working on a jQuery version of the same code to avoid using methods like `iFrames` to get this data. My jQuery function is:

```
$.get (
    page,
    function parse(data) {
        var r = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(r[0]["AssetId"]);
    }
);
```

I found ways to convert the `JSON` using jQuery, but I'm having trouble finding where the JSON code is that needs to be converted.

Comment: What response are you getting from the `get()` request? The response is what you'll want to convert into a JSON.

Comment: @Lix, I'm requesting this page http://goo.gl/xxHci0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the response from the server is a valid string representation of a JSON object, you'll be able to specify the `dataType` for the `get()` request. You could do something like this:

```
$.get( page, function( data ) {
  alert( data[0]["AssetId"] );
}, "json" ); // <-- here is the dataType
```

With the correct `dataType` set, you will not need to manually parse the data, it will arrive in your callback function as a JSON object.

References:

- [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

> jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). This converts your JSON string to a JavaScript object.

I threw  JSFiddle together for you using the facebook graph api:

http://jsfiddle.net/J4LCX/

```
$.getJSON( "http://graph.facebook.com/spikeh/",
    function( data ) {
        alert(data.id);
    });
```

Alternatively, to fix your code, just reference the object's id directly:

```
$.get (
    "http://graph.facebook.com/spikeh/",
    function parse(data) {
        alert(data.id);
    }
);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LBy9y/